# Renaming ZIP files according to the parent directory name

Tags: bash, unix, directory, zip

For a number of files I want to get the parent directory and append its name to the filename. For example, in the following path:

```
A/B/C/file.zip
```

I want to rename `file.zip` to `file_C.zip`.

Here is my code. I have to find directory which does not contain subdirectory and zip files in it, and I want to rename it to refer to the parent directory.

```
find ${WORKDIR} -daystart -mtime +3 -type d -links 2 -exec bash -c 'zip -rm "${1%}".zip "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure Bash solution:

```
find "$WORKDIR" -type f -name '*.zip' | while read file
do
  basename=$(basename "$file")
  dirname=$(dirname "$file")
  suffix=$(basename "$dirname")
  if [[ "$basename" != *"_${suffix}.zip" ]]; then
    mv -v "$file" "${dirname}/${basename%.zip}_${suffix}.zip"
  fi
done
```

The script processes all `*.zip` files found in `$WORKDIR` with a loop. In the loop it checks whether `$file` already has a suffix equal to the parent directory name. If it hasn't such suffix, the script renames the file appending `"_{parent_directory_name}"` to the filename just before the extension.

*Sample Tree*

```
A
├── B
│   ├── abc.zip.zip
│   └── C
│       └── file_C.zip
└── one.zip
```

*Sample Output*

```
‘./t/A/one.zip’ -> ‘./t/A/one_A.zip’
‘./t/A/B/abc.zip.zip’ -> ‘./t/A/B/abc.zip_B.zip’

A
├── B
│   ├── abc.zip_B.zip
│   └── C
│       └── file_C.zip
└── one_A.zip
```

where `WORKDIR=./t`.

Note, I deliberately simplified the `find` command, as it is not important for the algorithm. You can adjust the options according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for this job is the [`rename`](http://www.tecmint.com/rename-multiple-files-in-linux/) utility that comes with Perl.  (Beware that `util-linux` also contains a utility named `rename`.  It is not what you want.  If you have that on your system, investigate how to get rid of it and replace it with the one that comes with Perl.)

With this utility, it's as simple as

```
find $WORKDIR -name '*.zip' -exec \
    rename 's:/([^/]+)/(.+?)\.zip$:/${2}_${1}.zip:' '{}' +
```

You can stick *arbitrary Perl code* in that first argument, which makes it even more powerful than it looks from this example.

Note that your `find` command appears to do something unrelated, involving the *creation* of .zip files.